# raise ValueError(f"Cannot convert '{shape}' to a shape.") ValueError: Cannot convert '26' to a shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to create a Neural Network in Tensorflow using Keras for the first time but it keep giving this error please help
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\common\variables.py", line 406, in standardize_shape
raise ValueError(f"Cannot convert '{shape}' to a shape.")
ValueError: Cannot convert '26' to a shape.

Process finished with exit code 1

This is the code
def create_neural_network(data):
"""Creates a neural network with 2 hidden layers of size 128 nodes each and a softmax output layer with 10 nodes for each class (genre)

```
:param data (pandas.DataFrame): Input data
:return model: Neural network model
"""

# create network topology
model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(keras.Input(shape=(data.shape[1])))

# hidden layers
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2048, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))

# output layer
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer, loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics="accuracy"
)

return model
```

Answer (score 1):

shape needs to be a tuple, but `(data.shape[1])` will give you an int. Try `(data.shape[1],)`

Comment: Still giving same error
model.add(keras.Input(data.shape[1],))

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
model.add(keras.Input(shape=(data.shape[1], )))
```

This works for me.

Please check docu for 'shape' argument:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input

> shape:
> A shape tuple (integers), not including the batch size. For
> instance, shape=(32,) indicates that the expected input will be
> batches of 32-dimensional vectors. Elements of this tuple can be None;
> 'None' elements represent dimensions where the shape is not known.